# Correct Backbone.js collection event for when async data is retrieved

Tags: backbone.js

I want to render a view when a collection has been loaded asynchronously from the remote server.  I have the following collection class

```
class BusinessUnits extends Backbone.Collection
  model: BusinessUnit

  parse: (units) ->
    units
```

And then my view I was doing this:

```
  load: (businessUnits) =>
    @collection = businessUnits
    @collection.fetch()
    @render()
```

Obviously render() will be invoked before the fetch has been completed.

Is there a backbone.js event that is fired whenever the collection is fetched or would I be better firing my own?

This seems like a very common scenario.  How do people handle this type of situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the ["reset" event](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events) is what you are looking for.

> "reset" (collection) — when the collection's entire contents have been replaced.

This will be triggered after the fetch completes.

```
load: (businessUnits) =>
    @collection = businessUnits
    @collection.bind 'reset', => @render()
    @collection.fetch()
```

Comment: +1, although you don't need to create the anonymous function: `@collection.bind 'reset', @render`

Comment: @BrianGenisio: That will not work because then render will lose its scope, no? Collection.bind will not bind the scope to the current object (or does it)?

Comment: According to the backbone.js documentation 'to supply a context value for this when the callback is invoked, pass the optional third argument:': `@collection.bind 'reset', @render, @`

Comment: Assuming that render was defined with `=>` instead of `->`, it will work without passing in the context: `render: => # render your stuff`

Comment: Okay, that's true. I prefer to have backbone-defined "instance" methods to use `->`. And UI events are bound using `delegateEvents`, so they can also use `->` (backbone takes care of that). If this was not the `render` method, but a special, event-handler-only function, say `onBusinessUnitsLoaded`, then I might define it with `=>`. Just a matter of coding style, I guess.